# svn checkout repository on local disk to remote server

Tags: svn, local, svn-checkout

I have an svn repository that I keep on a usb drive. How do I checkout the local repository from a remote server in ssh? Something like svn checkout file://local_repository but on the remote server this doesn't exist. I am thinking maybe I have to chain svn command with scp?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to plug the USB drive into a remote server and get access to it from outside?

Comment: Please clarify your question. The svn repository is on a USB drive on your local system and you're trying to check out a working copy to a remote system?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not the server administrator, you should ask him/her how to acces it. Anyway, it's quite common to have a server set up that allows you to connect to the svn server via [ssh tunneling](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth). You could give it a try.